# Display marks in contour points

Tags: c#, winforms, teechart

I create a single contour and add it to the chart, add points with label text and also subscribe to the GetSeriesMark event, but the text is not displayed, and the event never gets fired

```
Contour contour1 = new Contour();
contour1.IrregularGrid = true;
// 
// contour1
contour1.Brush.Color = Color.FromArgb(68, 102, 163);
contour1.ColorEach = false;
contour1.EndColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 0, 0);
contour1.FillLevels = checkEditFillLevels.Checked;
// 
// 
contour1.Marks.Style = MarksStyles.Label;
contour1.Marks.Visible = true;
//
//
contour1.NumLevels = 8;
contour1.PaletteMin = 0;
contour1.PaletteStep = 0;
contour1.PaletteStyle = PaletteStyles.Pale;
// 
// 
contour1.Pen.Color = Color.FromArgb(192, 192, 192);
contour1.Pen.Style = DashStyle.Dot;
// 
// 
contour1.Pointer.HorizSize = 2;
// 
// 
contour1.Pointer.Pen.Visible = false;
contour1.Pointer.Style = PointerStyles.Rectangle;
contour1.Pointer.VertSize = 2;
contour1.Pointer.Visible = true;
contour1.StartColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192);
contour1.Title = "contour1";
```

Adding points is done with this

```
contour1.Add(x, y, z, "My Point 1");
```

Is there a way to display marks on the exact points in the Contour, and moreover is there a way to display marks only on specific points in the Contour (some points are actual data, others are made using interpolation to be able to show the contour)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is not possible to mark single points in contour (see [@Narcís Calvet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214639/narc%C3%ADs-calvet)'s answer), I ended up adding one Points series with marks on them. 
However, I still wanted only the Contour levels to be shown in the legend, and X axis to display it's values instead of Marks of the Points, so I needed to add following lines.

```
tChart1.Legend.LegendStyle = LegendStyles.Values;
tChart1.Legend.Series = _currentContour;
tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Style = AxisLabelStyle.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not, Contour series calculates and displays *isolines* from a custom array of X, Y and Z points. Levels are calculated automatically from users data. What would you like to get exactly? You might be interested in using Annotation tools. [Here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?t=8323) you can find an example about custom annotation tool positioning.

Comment: My data is a field with X and Y coordinates. So, there are physical objects at certain X, Y positions. So, for these points, I would like to display a marker "Name: X, Y, Value", so the user can see where these physical objects are placed on the map. All other points that I add to the contour are just calculated points to fulfill the grid requirement of the Contour, and should not have markers.

Comment: @beginner_developer can you please send us a simple example project so that we can try to suggest a solution to your needs? You can send your project to info at steema dot com to my attention. Thanks.